# Function views to Class based-views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

how can I change these views to Class Based-views, I have always wanted to know how to do this :c

I know Class Based-views are better thatn Fuction views, but i dont know the difference o how can I change a FW to CBV and do the same.

```
def login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'request': request, 'user': request.user
        })
    return render(request, 'login.html')

@login_required(login_url='/')
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could please help me :)

**EDIT**

Right now there are built-in class based views for this two things like LoginView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView so is much more easy to do this with CBV and LogoutView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView

If you want to implement or change this you should look to the documentation is really helpfull for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, View

class LoginTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

class HomeTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomeTemplateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_logout(request)
        return redirect('/')
```

I didn't test it but I think is that way. The TemplateView pass the request data to the template, so we don't have to declare again. If you need pass more data you can override the get_context_data method. In this page show you all methods in the CBV and the flow of the request/response. https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/

Comment: It's work! Thanks for the answer Harvey, now I'm understanding this much better. You're amazing :D

Good link, btw